# How to permanently delete a page on your site such that search engines no longer index it?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, 404

I have a domain managed with CrownPeak.  On this domain I have a page nested deeply within the site:

```
www.example.com/exampleFolder/anotherExampleFolder/lastExample.aspx
```

In my CMS, I've deleted the two folders and the `aspx` page. The problem is that the deleted page is indexed by Google. When the user visits my site, they just see my 404 page.  I'm afraid that this lowers the value of my SEO juice.

Comment: How long has it been deleted?   Google should drop the page from the index, but they need to crawl it first and they usually give 404 pages a grace period of 24 hours before removing them from the index.

Answer (score 1):

Block the url in robots.txt and use the url removal tool

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en

Make sure to keep serving 404 or 410 for the URL.